# What tense should I use if action is finished at the point I speak?

Tags: tense

I finished eating food at 3:00.
I want to know how I should have described it at 3:00.

I think the past tense can't be used because it is used if I finished eating food before 3:00.

But I also think the present progressive tense can't be used because it is used if I kept eating food at 3:00.

Then, what tense should I use in this case? Is it okay to use the present perfect tense in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as much about common sense as it is about the English language.

If you are saying the words out loud, you have presumably finished chewing the last mouthful, so you could say "I have just finished [eating] a meal" . (That's more idiomatic than 'eating food'.)

If you are thinking about it while eating (or talking with your mouth full!), you might think (or say) "I am just finishing a meal".